# Mysql query returns '0 rows affected' when applied to UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, subquery

I just don't understand why my update statement won't work.

Actually there are no errors. It just returns **0 Rows Affected**

```
Update releasing_schedule
Set Status ='Processing' Where promo_id =  (Select promo_list_id From  promo_list Where  promo_code ='ABC'  )
```

**The subquery itself returns 1 row** (list_id = **5**) but returns 0 affected when applied to UPDATE statement.

**2 tables:** 
releasing_schedule *and* promo_list

> releasing_schedule **promo_id** is the FK from promo_list table

Both promo_id and promo_list_id is type bigint

Also tried IN and some other type of operators but returns nothing.

Comment: In releasing_schedule do you have promo_id =5? or are both fields int?

Comment: @Mihai Yes, 5(promo_id) is there.

Comment: Did you try using an 'IN' instead of '=' between promo_id and your subquery? It doesn't make sense that changing that would make a difference since there is only one record returning, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: @BradSeman: you beat me to this suggestion. It does make sense because the select could potentially return multiple values.

Comment: Show us the full output including `Rows matched:`.  Show us a SELECT that confirms that the record in question isn't already set to Status 'Processing'.

Comment: @BradSeman . . . The query would return an error in that case.  I don't think it would follow up with "0 rows affected" in the event of an error, but that might depend on how the code is being called.

Comment: @pilcrow my default Status='Pending' and 5(promo_id) exist in releasing_schedule table

Comment: Update releasing_schedule
Set Status ='Processing' Where promo_id =5  does this work?

Comment: @Mihai Yes I'm the root admin. I run this through phpmyadmin Sql

Answer (score 1):

One of three things.  The subquery returns no rows (which you rule out).  Or, there is no matching `promo_id` in the `release_schedule` table.  Or the value for `status` is already `'Processing'`.  I assume that the value is already what you want to set it to.

```
Update releasing_schedule
Set Status ='Processing'
Where promo_id = (Select promo_list_id From  promo_list Where  promo_code ='ABC'  )
```

Comment: Thanks but my default Status='Pending' and 5(promo_id) exist in releasing_schedule table. I even tried IN and other operators but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry. I miss the subquery field: `promo_list_id`. It should be `list_id` only.

BUT **weird** happened. It did not throw any error (Unknown field) or something like that..

Comment: I guess your `release_schedule_table` has a column called `promo_list_id`. If that is the case then this works as required. MySQL is using the column from the outer table in the sub-query. This is another good reason to always qualify column names with the corresponding table (alias) whenever more than one table is involved in a SQL statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no other column named promo_list_id. I did try also other table to clarify this issue but still no error is thrown and found another weird things : If I will use unknown column(not found on any tables) it updates every row regardless of its FK and disregarding my Where clause condition on subquery..

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. If the column `promo_list_id` is not in any of the involved tables even MySQL will throw an error.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes..I know but I'm really sure there are no other field name the other table has.. maybe I really miss something.. Will try to replicate this on dummy table so I can see if this is real..